# How to running a simple for loop in parallel on GPU

Tags: python, gpu, numba

I am looking to do something very basic. I have a piece of code that I did not write which performs some processing that takes approximately 10 minutes to run on a single data set. I have 50,000 data sets, so I would like to utilize many GPUs to run this in parallel. I am familiar with how to do this on CPUs, however I do not know how to do this on GPUs. I see many examples of how to increase the speed the of certain function calls with GPUs via numba, although I cannot find how I would run a for loop on a gpu. Is this possible? In essence I have 50,000 image names, and I want a loop which reads through all images and performs the processing, then writes the extracted information to a .csv

Comment: **then writes the extracted information to a .csv** you cannot do this directly from the GPU in any existing API.

Comment: I thought this may be a problem. What do you suggest I do then? Can I just use GPUs to speed up the function calls as I've seen GPUs typically perform?

Comment: **In essence I have 50,000 image names, ... through all images and performs the processing**, are you talking about changing the image names in your file system? If so that's a CPU only task. If you meant you want to do any kind of processing on the images that can be paralelised you could use [PyCuda](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/) or [PyOpenCL](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/) to interact with the coressponding API's directly (depending on your GPU drivers). In both of these "languages" you typically write a function which is executed in many threads each having a uniqute thread id.

Comment: Hello, I am not talking about changing the names of the image systems. I am performing many manipulations, registrations, segmentations, etc on each of the sets of images. As such it takes about 10 minutes per image as it is running now. This is not feasible for 50k images obviously. So you are suggesting to speed up the function calls via GPUs, not to parallelize the outer for loop like I was proposing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm participate in Supercomputer Challenge.

From my experience, it's a complicated job to boost CPU code with GPU.
But there are some projects/libraries about python may help you.

```
CuPy: Easy to convert numpy code to CUDA code
Numba: JIT compiler which you mention above
PyCUDA: run C CUDA coda in Python
RAPDIS: cuXX which developed by Nvidia
```

easy -> hard : CuPy/RAPDIS > Numba > PyCUDA

In summary, you should study CuPy if you are using numpy, or try to find similar graphics processing methods in RAPDIS Library (ex:cuGraph). PyCUDA is the most difficult option for this case.

Just some suggestions, Speed up!